# C# navigating webbrowser from created combobox

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

I created visual web browser.

```
private void dodajKartę()
    {
        web = new WebBrowser();
        web.DocumentCompleted += web_DocumentCompleted1;
        web.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        web.Visible = true;
        web.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
        web.IsWebBrowserContextMenuEnabled = false;
        pasek = new ToolStrip();
        przyciskWstecz = new ToolStripButton();
        przyciskDalej = new ToolStripButton();
        pasekAdresu = new ToolStripComboBox();
        przyciskZamknijKartę = new ToolStripButton();
        przyciskMenu = new ToolStripDropDownButton();
        wszystkiePrzyciskiMenu(); // this metod define menu buttons
        WszystkoOPrzyciskach(); //this method define ToolStrip buttons
        tabControl1.TabPages.Add("Nowa karta");         
        tabControl1.SelectTab(i);
        tabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls.Add(web);
        tabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls.Add(pasek);
        i += 1;

    }
```

I would like to navigate my browser from created ToolStripComboBox
This code not working:``

```
((WebBrowser)tabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls[0]).Navigate((ToolStripComboBox)tabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls[10]).Text;
```

How can I change this code?

Comment: Break the code up, first get the selected item put it into a var, then do the navigate.  Set a break point prior to the navigate and you'll see the problem. You want whatever is selected to be the URL, the code above is always using the tabcontrol[10].text every time.

Comment: I change my navigate code to [code]            ((WebBrowser)tabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls[0]).Navigate(pasekAdresu.Text);
[/code], but browser navigate my closed tab

Comment: Method to close tab: <code>if (tabControl1.TabPages.Count - 1 > 0)
            {
                try
                {
                   
                    pasek.Items.Remove(pasekAdresu);
                    tabControl1.Controls.Remove(pasek);
                    tabControl1.Invoke(new Action(delegate ()
                    {
                        tabControl1.TabPages.RemoveAt(tabControl1.SelectedIndex);
                    }));
                    tabControl1.SelectTab(tabControl1.TabPages.Count - 1);
                    i -= 1;

                }
                catch
               {}